# What are the ways to migrate the traffic from an existing service to a new service, both the services consumes from same Kafka topic?

Tags: java, migration, kafka-consumer-api

what are the best ways to migrate the traffic from an existing service to a new service?
In my scenario, there's a service A that publishes something on Kafka Topic KA, there's a service B that consumes from this topic KA. Now I need to deprecate Service B and move the functionality to Service C. Service C also will consume the information from the same topic KA.

I am planning to keep both services B and C in the same consumer Group and create 2 partitions, service B from read from partition 1 and service C will consume from partition 2 also it will prevent duplicate request processing by both services B and C.

Also in Kafka can we configure how much % of traffic we want to send on which partition
or consumer 1 from a consumer group can consume x % of traffic while consumer 2 consumes (100-x)% of traffic?

Also, In case let's say controlling %g of traffic is possible, in case any failure occurs in new service C then how will I direct all the traffic to existing service B with minimum/no data loss?

What would be the best way to migrate the service in this scenario when both service needs to consume it from the same topic?